# Tests pass in my timezone, but fail on the remote/onshore/offshore Jenkins server

Tags: java, spring, datetime, jenkins, jodatime

When I am running my test cases locally it is running fine, but running in the Jenkins server it is failing. can someone help me with this?

TestCase Code:

```
@Test
public void testingError(){
    List<Error> validationError = subscriptionValidator.testError(String.valueOf(Instant.now().getEpochSecond()));
    Assert.assertEquals(Boolean.TRUE,validationError.isEmpty());
}
```

Code which i am testing:

```
public List<Error> testError(String epoch){
    List<Error> listError = new ArrayList<>();
    final Instant start = Instant.ofEpochSecond(Long.valueOf(epoch));

    //I need to check here if the date in start is a future date (only date)
    if(new DateTime(start.toEpochMilli(), DateTimeZone.getDefault()).withTimeAtStartOfDay().isAfter(DateTime.now())){
        final BadRequestException badRequestException =
                new BadRequestException(messageByLocale.getMessage("error-message.invalid-start-date"));
        throw badRequestException;
    }
    return listError;
}
```

Even if i run the test cases using the command `mvn  -Dspring.profiles.active=local -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true test package`  in my local it is giving this error

```
    testingError(com.demo.service.v1.subscription.ValidatorTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
com.impelsys.catalog.exception.BadRequestException: null
        at com.demo.service.v1.subscription.Validator.testError(Validator.java:305)
        at com.demo.service.v1.subscription.ValidatorTest.testingError(ValidatorTest.java:319)
```

My local default time zone is UTC and my Jenkins default time zone is also UTC.

-----------------------------UPDATE--------------------------------------

With the above code when running the test cases `Instant.now() or DateTime.now()` are giving the date `1970-01-01` that why the if the condition becomes true and it is throwing the BadRequestException.

now the question is why it is giving `1970-01-01`?

Comment: You should also post the test case code.

Comment: So you're setting the start date and time as a String containing the number of seconds since epoch? Why not just the long value in that case? And I don't see how this could fail, do you get any exception or failed assertations?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash you mean the entire test case code?

Comment: @Thomas in shopDTO this StartDateAndTime is a string i cannot change it so that's why converting it to a string. it is giving failed assertion.

Comment: That failing test code doesn't seem to be connected to your first line, at least I can't see any obvious connection. I _guess_ that `start.toEpochMilli()` is somehow related to `setStartDateAndTime()` but since that takes a string there's still a lot missing. Also, _what_ assertation if failing, are you getting that `BadRequestException` but don't expect it?

Comment: Btw, you are using Joda Time, aren't you? `DateTime` isn't a `java.time` class.

Comment: Yes i am using joda time

Comment: Isn’t that a matter of specifying your intended time zone instead of `DateTimeZone.getDefault()`? For example `DateTimeZone.forID("America/Tortola")` (don’t know which time zone you wanted).

Comment: @OleV.V. Updated the code with minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I can’t reproduce. I rewrote your code a bit, but your `if` statement is intact. I ran it in different time zones behind, on and ahead of UTC. Your method always returned an empty list and never threw. Which is your local default time zone and the default time zone of your Jenkins? At which time(s) of day does your test fail on Jenkins? I figure the time of day could make a difference.

Comment: To me it makes no sense that this test should fail in any time zone whatsoever. Your test takes the current time. Throws away fraction of second, which gives us a slightly earlier time. Your method regulates the time back to the start of day in some time zone, giving us a yet earlier time (even in all the corner cases I can think of). Then comparing the obtained time to the current time now (which is some nanos later than the time the method was called). And apparently thinks that the earlier time is later and throws the exception?? Are you sure you can still reproduce your example?

Comment: If your test is still failing, insert some debug logging printing the values of all dates and times in play whether as `Instant`, `long`, `String` or `DateTime` to narrow down where something doesn’t go as expected.

Comment: when i tried to print the `Instant.now()` in test cases i am getting `1970-01-20` but that same value in my code is giving today's date `24-11-2022`

Comment: My local default time zone is UTC and my Jenkins default time zone is also UTC

Comment: 1970-01-20 comes from confusing seconds and milliseconds since the epoch at some point. Current seconds since the epoch are 1 669 325 605. This many *milliseconds* since the epoch equals `1970-01-20T07:42:05.605Z` (UTC). And the other date you mentioned, 1970-01-01, is the epoch (or 0 seconds since the epoch).

Comment: The results you are reporting are not coming out of the code you are showing us. In this situation we can’t help.

Answer (score 0):

I would still need more code from your test, but I have the following assumption:

The test is failing because your Jenkins server operates on a different timezone than your local machine. You need to adapt your unit test, so that the result is independent of the executing environment.

You can set the default TimeZone for unit tests as follows:

```
@Test
@DefaultTimeZone("CET")
void test_with_short_zone_id() {
    assertThat(TimeZone.getDefault()).isEqualTo(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
}

@Test
@DefaultTimeZone("Africa/Juba")
void test_with_long_zone_id() {
    assertThat(TimeZone.getDefault()).isEqualTo(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Juba"));
}
```

source: https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/default-locale-timezone/#defaulttimezone

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. You don’t want to set the default time zone. You want to correct your code to work regardless of the default time zone. You also want to avoid using the `TimeZone` class since it is troublesome and outdated.

Comment: this @DefaultTimeZone notation is not present how to enable it